# error with connecting my react app with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and I am blocked when I try to synchronize my firebase data base with my state in the componentWillMount. I think is because the lesson I have and the langage has been update.

this is base.js

```
import Rebase from 're-base';

    const base = Rebase.createClass({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBYurAdM8P7Pt7xdLPb3TXqqGh4oFKyGjY",
    authDomain: "ma-chat-box-e1482.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://ma-chat-box-e1482.firebaseio.com",
 });

export default base;
```

And my componentWillMount is

```
  import base from 'base';
    componentWillMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState('/', { // this line send me an error !
        context: this,
        state: 'messages'
    });
}
```

and the error is :

```
ypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_base___default.a.syncState is not a function
```

thank for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. it was in my base page base.js

is

```
import Rebase from 're-base';

var base = Rebase.createClass({
   apiKey: "*****",
   authDomain: "*****",
   databaseURL: "*****",
   storageBucket: "*****",
   messagingSenderId: "*****"
});

export default base;
```